# Just Friends… in code golf

Tags: code-golf, cellular-automata

We already have challenges dealing with simulating vanilla [Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3434/110698), [Wireworld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9292/110698) and [rule 110](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34505/110698), but so far none corresponding to a ([specific](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203616)) non-totalistic rule. So here is one.

In June 2000 David Bell described the [Just Friends](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/OCA:Just_Friends) rule, which uses the same square grid and two states as regular Life but has the following transitions:

- A live cell remains live iff it has one or two live neighbours
- A dead cell becomes live iff it has two live neighbours **and they are not vertically or horizontally adjacent**

The birth restriction prevents the explosive behaviour that would otherwise be seen with birth-on-2-neighbours rules such as [Seeds](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/OCA:Seeds), and instead allows many interesting patterns. I've been searching for small oscillators of every period in this rule using [apgsearch](https://catagolue.hatsya.com/census/b2-as12), and by that program alone I have found a [stable reflector](https://conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2442&start=25#p152722).

### Task

Given a Just Friends input pattern and number of generations, output the resulting pattern. The simulation grid, if bounded, must have size at least 40×40 and use either of the following boundary conditions:

- Wrap around like a torus
- Off-grid cells are dead

Pattern input and output may be in any reasonable format, such as binary matrices, lists of live cell positions and [RLE](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Run_Length_Encoded).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

These are in the form

```
input pattern
number of generations
output pattern.
```

```
....
.*..
.**.
....
1
....
.*..
.**.
....

......
..*...
..*...
.*....
......
......
......
12
......
......
......
....*.
....*.
...*..
......

.................
........*........
.................
......*.*........
.................
.**..............
.......**........
.................
.................
.................
.................
.................
.................
59
.................
.................
.................
.................
.........*.*..*..
..............*..
...........*.....
.................
.................
.................
.............*...
.............*...
.................

........................
...........*............
........................
......*....*.*..........
......*.................
.............*...*......
.....*.*...........**...
.................*......
........................
........................
...*.*..................
....................*.*.
.*.*....................
..................*.*...
........................
........................
......*.................
...**...........*.*.....
......*...*.............
.................*......
..........*.*....*......
........................
............*...........
........................
29
........................
............*...........
........................
..........*.*....*......
.................*......
......*...*.............
...**...........*.*.....
......*.................
........................
........................
..................*.*...
.*.*....................
....................*.*.
...*.*..................
........................
........................
.................*......
.....*.*...........**...
.............*...*......
......*.................
......*....*.*..........
........................
...........*............
........................

...............
.*.............
.*.***.........
..*...**.......
.....*..*......
..*...**.......
.*.***.........
.*.............
...............
15
...............
....*..........
....*.*****....
.....*.....**..
..........*..*.
.....*.....**..
....*.*****....
....*..........
...............

...........................
..........*.....*..........
..........*.....*..........
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
.*.......................*.
.*.........**.**.........*.
.*.......................*.
.*.........**.**.........*.
.*.......................*.
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
..........*.....*..........
..........*.....*..........
...........................
83
...........................
..........*.....*..........
..........*.....*..........
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
.*.......................*.
.*.........**.**.........*.
.*.......................*.
.*.........**.**.........*.
.*.......................*.
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................
..........*.....*..........
..........*.....*..........
...........................

...........
..*........
..*......*.
....*....*.
.***.....*.
....*....*.
..*......*.
..*........
...........
21
...........
..*........
..*......*.
....*....*.
.***.....*.
....*....*.
..*......*.
..*........
...........

...............
...............
..**.**.*****..
..*.*.*.*****..
...***..**.**..
..*.*.*.*****..
..**.**.*****..
...............
...............
1
...............
....*..*.......
..*...*........
...............
.*.............
...............
..*...*........
....*..*.......
...............
```

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258704/custom-games-of-life

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES11), 136 bytes

Expects `(n)(binary_matrix)` and returns another binary matrix.

```javascript
n=>g=m=>n--?g(m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>[p=c=t=0,...'12587630'].map(d=>t+=(c|=p&(p=m[y+~-(d/3)]?.[x+d%3-1]),d)&&~~p)|6>>t&(v|~t&!c)))):m
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVXNjtMwED4i-SlCJBp72g5Nqy6FlbMnuHLYY9tDlJ8S1DohzVattvTMO3BZod2HgufgAchvmyZOWCQWcrAzP9_MN-Ox_PVe-LZz983lDzeR2598_yK4seArboh-_2pBV7gyA0rD3o5xI8yETW8bC9OAWzzigx4iavpwPHl1MRpo89TF5kbU5dTa86BDA76a7rqHPrVfjtj8Cqfbrv1i1NfnrGezTudwCNj-wjCiDt3sD1HnucXi780q5_MzdD7deKFDNXetMQwd037nLZ3rnbDogGHkX0ehJxaU4TpYehFVZ2ImVIauH741rQ90rXBDuSWKsnQixVS4sj45qqyniFjVNTHwA8ouY7fExUyLCBPkNK4uzIqyEllFUNETtrN979KEaYKxfLH2lw4u_QV1qWDUZKcIWdM2BXi6mTP86HuCahor_mZCY0pXSfdL8plltd_9eHYbp0eCkC4QL4mok3RPdInltEGulGz6sACVvqMGapqqD7T7AFQ1Oez3kZ9CM34tqVbiDk0GGQKyBeSGFkpw8iFYC5L1qJ78DNHMSm4ACSk5IvEkcn8pAlBO9zGssKlXZ-NTcCkhoIaokqoaoDiuR7Gqc2tGDOuzRWoE4_SlmvILetQUU1CiV7FX8e0NIPq4ed6x0pfT-ie2tpj_yCadUMR8fo8SlKcJngjXxvO_2f7e2U5GZ_NEzl8IKEKSY8y0XwBS_Zm_9D0gQ11yp2pydkQAaSKS3fGynDHID1Jir-Lb8-nZI_wL)

#### Method

In order to get the neighbors of the cell at \$(x,y)\$, we use \$d\in\{0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8\}\$ and do:

$$\big(x+(d \bmod 3)-1,y+\lfloor d/3\rfloor-1\big)$$

which maps \$d\$ to:

$$\begin{matrix}0&1&2\\3&&5\\6&7&8\end{matrix}$$

More specifically, we start with \$d=0\$ and go clockwise, ending with \$d=0\$ again. While doing so, we keep track of the number of live neighbors in \$t\$ and set \$c=1\$ as soon as we detect two consecutive live cells.

The top-left cell is processed twice so that all consecutive pairs are tested (for the flag \$c\$), but we make sure to update \$t\$ only once. The distinction between the two passes is made possible by using the falsy integer `0` the first time and the truthy character `'0'` the second time.

Using \$t\in[0,8]\$, \$c\in\{0,1\}\$ and the current value \$v\in\{0,1\}\$ of the cell, we compute the new state with:

```javascript
//     .-----------------> the LSB is set iff t=1 or t=2
//     |      .----------> always true if the cell is live
//     |      |      .---> true if t is even and c was not set
//   __|_     |    __|__
//  /    \    |   /     \
    6 >> t & (v | ~t & !c)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυＦＮ«ＵＭυ⟦⟧ＦⅉＦＬθ«Ｊλκ⊞§υκ§.*⎇⁼*ＫＫ¬÷⊖№ＫＭ*²›⁼²№ＫＭ*№×²⪫ＫＭω**»⎚Ｅυ⪫κω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZA9a8MwEIZn61cIT7JxMwQ6lEzFKSWhCYZmKaWDal9jYVlyFClpKfnt7kmJh6ZfUw8Ep9Pzvrq7suam1Fz2/b4WEiibqc7Ze2uEWrMkoYXb1sxlVCQTUmDRMofZizYncunaZzCefCfRgne5bluuKi95fEIyCuiDB0J2B2pta7Y5CqK5a7uVZjKjjYej8N21nakKXr1Hk2R0uMajNM7oCozi5o3dbByXWxb7WgHQ4A8ZXWqLbdmp2IkK2BRKAy0oCxXLtcPePbjQ2gBDGKVeM8Zza4BbHONkOs7oD/zwsBItBG6uhfqM7ZPAenMMHOpAolwCxyXh5bhDXJSfLoibIJmQQ9@PzoMMSfqlcs6kvzNp@r1z@rfzf1TI5VV/sZMf) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input like the test cases except with a blank line between the pattern and number of generations. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυ
```

Read the pattern and write it to the canvas.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat for each generation.

```
ＵＭυ⟦⟧
```

Start collecting the new pattern.

```
ＦⅉＦＬθ«Ｊλκ
```

For each cell...

```
⊞§υκ§.*⎇⁼*ＫＫ¬÷⊖№ＫＭ*²›⁼²№ＫＭ*№×²⪫ＫＭω**
```

... apply the generation rules to the cell.

```
»⎚Ｅυ⪫κω
```

Write the new pattern to the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) + my [LifeFind](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/LifeFind) package, 65 bytes

```
<<Life`
Last@CellularAutomaton[{RuleNumber@"12/2-a",2,{1,1}},##]&
```